# continuous probability: average power of a Gaussian random variable $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My book states that $E[X^2]$ is the average power. It then says for $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, the average power is $\frac{1}{2}$ and for $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{2}$.

How can this be?

The second moment of the Gaussian is $\mu^2 + \sigma^2$ so the average power for $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ should be one and $\sigma^2$ for $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

It makes since to multiple by $1/2$ since we average by $1/N$ but the book just states the average power is $E[X^2]$ not $\frac{1}{2}E[X^2]$.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a random variable $X$ is called Gaussian $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ if its density (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) equals

$$p(x;\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right). \tag{1}$$

However, some books define this differently: They say that $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ if its density equals

$$q(x;\mu,\sigma^2) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2} \right).$$

Note that $$q(x;\mu,\sigma^2) = p\left(x;\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right). \tag{2}$$ The first definition gives

$$\mathbb{E}X = \mu \qquad \mathbb{E}(X^2)= \mu^2+\sigma^2$$

whereas the second one gives, by $(2)$,

$$\mathbb{E}X = \mu \qquad \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mu^2+ \frac{\sigma^2}{2}.$$

So, just check carefully the definition of normal distribuition in the book. If the author sticks with the standard definition $(1)$, then you are right and it should read $\sigma^2$ instead of $\sigma^2/2$.

Comment: The author uses definition (1).

Comment: Well, then you are right.